# Changing the orientation of a pose goal in rviz (python)

Tags: python, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Coming off the back of the rviz tutorials, I've been trying to control the panda arm using only the pose goal but cannot change it's orientation. Changing the "pose_goal.orientation.w" value seems to do nothing and although I've read that rviz uses quaterion values to define orientation I can't understand how this translates to what I'd write in my code to achieve a specific orientation.
My goal is to be able to set an orientation for the arm based on coordinates in Cartesian space and either values for pitch/roll/yaw or a direction vector

Here is the part of my code defining the pose goal

```
def go_to_pose_goal(self):

move_group = self.move_group

print("Starting planning to go to pose goal.\n")
pose_goal = geometry_msgs.msg.Pose()


pose_goal.orientation.w = 1
pose_goal.orientation.x = 1
pose_goal.orientation.y = 1
pose_goal.orientation.z = 1
pose_goal.position.x = 1
pose_goal.position.y = -0.518
pose_goal.position.z = 0.8

move_group.set_pose_target(pose_goal)

plan = move_group.go(wait=True)
move_group.stop()
move_group.clear_pose_targets()

current_pose = self.move_group.get_current_pose().pose
return all_close(pose_goal, current_pose, 0.01
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/360769/changing-the-orientation-of-a-pose-goal-in-rviz-(python)/) by [Matt Gibbon](https://answers.ros.org/users/58905/matt-gibbon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-09-01

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-09-02**:\

> Coming off the back of the rviz tutorials

please always *link* to whatever you are referring to.

We can't know what you consider "the rviz tutorials".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I would recommend to take a look at [wiki/tf2/Tutorials/Quaternions](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Quaternions) in addition to a general introduction to what quaternions are (there are various textbooks (ie: math) and sites which discuss them, such as ), as I believe that's mostly where your confusion comes from.

> Changing the "pose_goal.orientation.w" value seems to do nothing and although I've read that rviz uses quaterion values to define orientation I can't understand how this translates to what I'd write in my code to achieve a specific orientation

Changing the `w` element of a quaternion is not something you typically do manually: it's not the ya`w` component (there is no yaw component directly in a quaternion).

> My goal is to be able to set an orientation for the arm based on coordinates in Cartesian space and either values for pitch/roll/yaw or a direction vector

As mentioned on [wiki/tf2/Tutorials/Quaternions: Think in RPY then convert to quaternion](http://wiki.ros.org/tf2/Tutorials/Quaternions#Think_in_RPY_then_convert_to_quaternion), you can do this by using convenience/conversion functions from (for instance) the `tf.transformations` library:

```
from tf.transformations import quaternion_from_euler
  
if __name__ == '__main__':

  # RPY to convert: 90deg, 0, -90deg
  q = quaternion_from_euler(1.5707, 0, -1.5707)

  print "The quaternion representation is %s %s %s %s." % (q[0], q[1], q[2], q[3])
```

(this code is just a copy-paste from the linked wiki page)

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2020-09-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-09-02**:
See also #q9981 for a *very* old Q&A about this.

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-09-02**:
Note also btw: this has nothing to with RViz.

RViz only visualises external data. It's not a simulation or anything which maintains its own environment.

**Comment by [Matt Gibbon](https://answers.ros.org/users/58905/matt-gibbon/) on 2020-09-10**:
Thankyou, this has been very helpful